# Pushing docker image to GCR from shell script doesn't work but works fine from terminal

Tags: docker, powershell, shell, google-cloud-platform, google-container-registry

I'm trying to push a Docker image to GCR from a shell script but I keep getting this error:

> unauthorized: You don't have the needed permissions to perform this operation, and you may have invalid credentials

I'm not sure that it is permissions problem because if I leave aside WSL2 and run the command below in Powershell the image gets pushed no problem.

```
docker --debug push gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/IMAGE_NAME:latest
```

Funny think is running the script in the same PS window will produce the error. The error points to [this](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication) documentation, which I tried to follow but to no avail.

Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
set -ex

# Define variables
PROJECT_ID="XXXXX"
IMAGE_NAME="XXXXX"
SERVICE_NAME="XXXXX"
REGION="XXXXX"

function load_env_vars() {
  local env_file="$1"
  local env_vars=""

  while IFS="=" read -r key value; do
    env_vars="${env_vars} --set-env-vars ${key}=${value}"
  done < "${env_file}"

  echo "${env_vars}"
}

# Authenticate to GCP
gcloud auth configure-docker

# Build the Docker image
docker build -t gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/${IMAGE_NAME} .

# Push the Docker image to Google Container Registry
docker --debug push gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/${IMAGE_NAME}:latest

# Load environment variables from .env file
env_vars=$(load_env_vars ".env")

# Deploy the image to Cloud Run
gcloud run deploy ${SERVICE_NAME} \
    --image gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/${IMAGE_NAME} \
    --region ${REGION} \
    --platform managed \
    --verbosity=debug \
    --allow-unauthenticated \
    ${env_vars}
```

Comment: Which command in your shell script is generating the error?

Comment: @JohnHanley This one: docker --debug push gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/${IMAGE_NAME}:latest

Comment: `echo $HOME` and `echo $USER` in both environments and make sure the path is the same. If you are using different users or sudo, then the credential helper and gcloud will look in different locations.

Comment: Why is your post tagged with PowerShell?

Comment: You have posted a Bash shell script. How are you running the script?

Comment: I was running it on PowerShell but on WSL2 the same happens

Comment: What is the result of $HOME and $USER in the working and failing environment?

Comment: In the failing one

$USER
 Command 'valar' not found, did you mean:
  command 'vala' from deb valac-bin (0.56.0-1)
  command 'valac' from deb valac-bin (0.56.0-1)
Try: sudo apt install <deb name>

$HOME
-bash: /home/valar: Is a directory

Working:
$USER
Nothing

$HOME
C:\Users\victor

Comment: There is your problem. Different users, different directories (/home/valar versus /home/victor). The CLI gcloud is looking for credentials in the wrong location. Edit your post and include those details and how you are running scripts. Reading comments with those details is challenging. Clearly specifying everything is important.

Comment: I think they are different because one is PS the other WSL. I will edit the post to include more details, thanks mate!

Comment: The credentials are stored in a user's home directory. Different users, different credentials.

Comment: What version of Docker are you using,  The link says : Warning: The Docker credential helper is only supported for Docker 18.03 or above. A bug in earlier versions of the Docker client slows down docker build dramatically when credential helpers are configured.